# Reporting effect sizes of non-significant interaction and pairwise comparisons?

Tags: anova, interaction, effect-size

I conducted a study in which I had two groups (A and B) and participants' speed was measured during each two activities (writing by hand and typing). I made 2 hypotheses about the interaction.

1. Participants in Group A would be faster at writing than Group B.
2. Participants in Group A would be faster at typing than Group B.

I did a 2x2 factorial ANOVA and pairwise comparisons. The interaction was not significant. Same for the pairwise comparisons of Group A and B for writing and Group A and B for typing. HOWEVER, the effect sizes (partial eta squared) were decent (.009 to .012). Would it be appropriate to report the non-signifcant pairwise comparisons with the effect sizes? Or is it incorrect to even do the pairwise comparisons of a non-significant interaction?

Comment: If the interaction is not significant I would not report the pairwise comparisons. I would focus on the main effects. But I guess this really depends on what you are doing with the results.

Comment: The participants in Group A vs. Group B were given different instructions for what needed to be done. My interest is in the effect of the instructions (main effect which was also non-significant with medium effect size) and if differences in speed between the two instructions depends on writing vs. typing (interaction). I thought to report the effect sizes to be able to say it's not significant, but there is a sizable effect.

Comment: I guess if it is a sizable effect then it is worth reporting- I just wouldn't overstate it. But the question that comes to mind is why it not-significant. Did you have enough power to detect an effect?

Comment: I ran a power analysis beforehand and I only needed 34 participants. I have 140 so there should be enough power.

Comment: I think what your results are telling you is that even though you had adequate power you still did not detect a significant effect. If those are sizable effect sizes then there must be a lot of variability in the estimates. I think if you wanted to report the effect sizes you have to mention why you didn't see any significant effects.